# Count no of colons in col1 and trim the data after that total no of colons in col2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below data

```
Name        Description
a-c-v       ad-cfd-gft-anonmymous data-typegf
t-r         tsjdg-dgdt-testing the data-check the test-type
f           test-1234-tlelephone
```

I need the sql query that will give me the results as

```
ad-cfd-gft
tsjdg-dgdt
test
```

Depending on the colons in the name i should get the results from description.
I am using sql server 2008,can you please help
Edited my data as well

Comment: Try one of the following. You are looking for a pattern or a `char` in a `string` and its position. `CHARINDEX (Transact-SQL) PATINDEX (Transact-SQL)` and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Where are the colons?

Answer (score 0):

```
select  name
       ,cast (Description.query('/r/e[position() <= sql:column("tokens_num")]/text()') as varchar(max)) as Description

from   (select  name
               ,len(name) - len(replace(name,'-','')) + case when name = '' then 0 else 1 end  as tokens_num
               ,cast ('<r><e>' + replace(Description,'-','</e><e>-') + '</e></r>' as xml)      as Description

        from    t
        ) t
```

---

```
+-------+-------------+
| name  | Description |
+-------+-------------+
| a-c-v | ad-cfd-gft  |
+-------+-------------+
| t-r   | tsjdg-dgdt  |
+-------+-------------+
| f     | test        |
+-------+-------------+
```

---

Demo (with more easier to follow data sample)

```
declare @t table (Name varchar(100),Description varchar(100))

insert into @t values 

     (''                    ,'It''s-a-show-about-nothing')
    ,('Sting'               ,'Englishman-In-New-York')
    ,('Paul-Simon'          ,'The-Sound-Of-Silence')
    ,('Andrew-Lloyd-Webber' ,'The-Phantom-Of-The-Opera')



select      name            
           ,name_tokens_num
           ,Description                                                                                                 as original_Description
           ,cast (Description_xml.query('/r/e[position() <= sql:column("name_tokens_num")]/text()') as varchar(max))    as new_Description

from       (select      name
                       ,Description
                       ,len(name) - len(replace(name,'-','')) + case when name='' then 0 else 1 end  as name_tokens_num
                       ,cast ('<r><e>' + replace(Description,'-','</e><e>-') + '</e></r>' as xml)    as Description_xml

            from        @t
            ) t
```

---

```
+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| name                | name_tokens_num | original_Description     | new_Description |
+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
|                     | 0               | It's-a-show-about-nothing|                 |
+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Sting               | 1               | Englishman-In-New-York   | Englishman      |
+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Paul-Simon          | 2               | The-Sound-Of-Silence     | The-Sound       |
+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Andrew-Lloyd-Webber | 3               | The-Phantom-Of-The-Opera | The-Phantom-Of  |
+---------------------+-----------------+--------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but i need the data depending on the colons mentioned in the name if there are 2 colons (-) then the description should be presented as total of 2 colons and remaining should be truncated.Please check the edited data

Comment: I updated the answer as for you request. Had a chance to test it yet?